# Does Android keep track of app uninstallations

Tags: android

Does anyone know if Android keeps track of installations and uninstallations of sideloaded apps anywhere apart from the log stream?

Want to be able to test if a package name has been recently uninstalled - but I imagine no such record is kept.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

seems like it's possible to get list of tracked uninstalled packages.

the way to do that:  use the `PackageManager.getInstalledApplications()` with flag `GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES`

calling this method with this flag should provide you with list of all packages which been uninstalled, if uninstalled with specifying the flag `DONT_DELETE_DATA` explicitly

more information on the Android developers page: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications(int)

Comment: +1 thanks - i think you mean _"__with__ specifying the flag DONT_DELETE_DATA explicitly"_

Comment: @Dori: actually I did not tried it myself, so I'll be glad if you tell me if it works as accpected..